# How do i use `tabbing` with `itemize`/`enumerate`?

Tags: enumerate, itemize, tabbing

I want to use `tabbing` with `itemize`/`enumerate`. What is the proper syntax for it?

I want the result to look something like this:

```
1. Bullet text -> More text    ->  Some more text
  * Sub bullet -> Aligned text ->  More text
  * Sub Tab    -> Aligned text ->  More text
2. More bullet -> Aligned      ->  Aligned
  * Sub bullet -> Aligned text ->  More text
  * Sub Tab    -> Aligned text ->  More text
3. More bullet -> Aligned      ->  Aligned
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this? An `enumerate` environment, then a `tabularx` of a suitable width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
  \item \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\leftmargini}[t]{@{}*{3}\{>{arraybackslash{X}}@{}}
          Bullet text & More text & Some more text \\
          \textbullet \hspace{\labelsep} Sub bullet & Aligned text & More text \\
          \textbullet \hspace{\labelsep} Sub Tab & Aligned text & More text
        \end{tabularx}

  \item begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\leftmargini}[t]{@{}*{3}\{>{arraybackslash{X}}@{}}
          Bullet text. Some more text. Some more text & More text & Some more text \\
          \textbullet \hspace{\labelsep} Sub bullet & Aligned text & More text \\
          \textbullet \hspace{\labelsep} Sub Tab & Aligned text & More text
        \end{tabularx}

  \item \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\leftmargini}[t]{@{}*{3}\{>{arraybackslash{X}}@{}}
          More bullet & Aligned & Aligned
        \end{tabularx}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]